# AWS: pip install returns "IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device" when there is space

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install tensorflow on a AWS instance but I'm getting an error:

```
>>sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (123.4MB): 4.1kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 442, in _download_url
    fp.write(chunk)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

I do have space:

```
>> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.4G   12K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  784K  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      197G  8.0G  181G   5% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        64G   52M   61G   1% /mnt
overflow        1.0M 1020K  4.0K 100% /tmp
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? In general, you should not use sudo with pip, and should not try to modify the system installed Python.

Comment: please note the `overflow` entry for `/tmp`. This is the problem in a nutshell - it's mounted a 1M ramdisk on `/tmp` to allow `/tmp` operations to work at some point because it thought `/` was full. Do `sudo umount /tmp` to allow it to be used again. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590344/ioerror-no-space-left-on-device-which-device) and [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60731/overflow-tmp-mounted-when-there-is-free-space-on) for more details.